# LibLinphone 5.x cannot encode "gzip" content

Tags: linphone, linphone-sdk

Im using Linphone SDK 5.x and try to get compressed data(gzip) from my server(by notify).
the header is set to Content-Encoding: gzip
however its cannot encode it with this warning:
"WARNING belle_sip_memory_body_handler_unapply_encoding: unknown encoding 'gzip'"

[image]

this is working with the previous Linphone SDK 3.x,
am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

First check that your linphone-sdk was built with ZLIB dependency.
Then replace the Content-Encoding in your NOTIFY from "gzip" to "deflate".

Cheers,